# ¿Como realizo una suma de input dinamicos? php

Tags: php

```
<html>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/estilo.css">

 <body>

 <form method="post">

 <h1>Promedio De Calificaciones</h1>


   <hr><br>

   <h3>¿Cuantas Calificaciones Tienes? </h3><input type="number" name="nump">

   <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" class="boton">

 </form>

  <?php

  for($i=0; $i<$_POST['nump']; $i++){

    echo '<h4>Ingresa la Calificacion: </h4>';

    echo "<input type='number' name='num'/> <br><br>";

  }
  $total = $_REQUEST['numero1']+$_REQUEST['numero2'];

  echo "El total de la suma es: ".$total;

  echo "<input type='submit' class='boton' value='Promedio'/>";

  echo 'El promedio es: '.$promedio;
    ?>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza  la fincion intval($dato_string), dedo que en los request, y post recives string, que recupera php de la peticion http POST en el siguiente enlase puedes encontrar mas informacion de su oso y otras finciones: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php

ademas el input tienes que nombrarlo

```
<input type="number" name="name[]">
```

y lo procesas asi, teniendo varios de esos:

```
$arr=$_POST[name];
$num=0;
foreach($arr as $value){
     $num+=intval($value);
}
```